# Class member assigned to None or null or _ in scala which is better and why?

Tags: scala

I have a Scala domain class (intended for persistence to database)
like:

```
class Foo() {

var bar: Long = _ // or None or null ???
var jaz: String = _ // or None or null or empty string "" ???
}
```

How the answer is influenced if the fields bar and jaz are required fields as opposed to
being optional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Programming in Scala:

> An initializer “= _” of a field
>   assigns a zero value to that field.
>   The zero value depends on the field’s
>   type. It is 0 for numeric types, false
>   for booleans, and null for reference
>   types. This is the same as if the same
>   variable was defined in Java without
>   an initializer. Note that you cannot
>   simply leave off the “= _” initializer
>   in Scala ... [as it] would declare an abstract variable, not an uninitialized one

So your code above is the same as

```
class Foo() {

var bar: Long = 0
var jaz: String = null
}
```

Kim's answer sounds correct - if a field is optional, make it an Option, if not, make the constructor set it.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Option` makes it clear to the user of the class that the value is optional. Using null is discouraged in Scala and would surprise other developers. It also doesn't "show up" in the type. If the field isn't optional, just don't use `Option` and make the fields contructor parameters. Don't provide a constructor that would leave the object in an invalid state after creation.